# How to correct Boostrap cards with images from overextending and taking extra white spaces?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The height of my bootstrap cards is extending way too much when I am adding images. Is there any way to keep the cards from not overextending?

[image: Cards without images ~ Perfect]

[image: Cards with images ~ Overflowing and covering the next element]

Comment: How about cutting and pasting the actual error message, rather than paraphrasing it.  Also, are you certain that it refers to the method you have presented?  If so, then which line is it flagging?

Comment: As a matter of style, I strongly recommend always using a block (`{ ... }`) for the bodies of loops and compound statements such as `if`, `else`, *etc*, even when the body contains only one statement.  Failure to follow that practice can lead to trouble, related to human misinterpretation of the code, and in particular, it has contributed to at least one high-profile security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments on the question, you are asking about a style recommendation from your IDE, related specifically to:

> ```
>     if (myRoot == null) return myRoot;
> ```

Your IDE means that when that particular `return` statement is executed, `myRoot` is always `null`.  It is obvious that this is so, because the `if` ensures that otherwise, that `return` is not executed.  Your IDE is recommending that you change that to

```
    if (myRoot == null) return null;
```

Whether you do so is up to you, but personally, I would go with your IDE's advice, because it makes the code slightly clearer.

Comment: That is fair enough..
But the issue is that this does not delete the desired node from my binary search tree. There is no change in my binary tree after i use this method. I was looking a reason for that. I dont think this answers my question. I am looking for a logical error and i cannot find any.

Comment: @spiritmonster, as far as I can tell, your question is about the message that `myRoot` will always be null.  This is what I have answered.  If you are *also* having trouble with those parts of the method that you have implemented doing the job that they are intended to do, then that would be the subject of an altogether different question.  And when you post that one, do be sure to include a [mre], for what you have presented in this question is not sufficient to answer the one you now seem to want to pose.